# AngularJS - opening a link in new tab to change ng-show value instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tabs

What I'm working on an AngularJS website. A colleague has suggested that the downside to the dynamic solution is that whether you open a button in a new tab (for example an "About Us" tab), it takes you back to the first page and refreshes it. I'm using the ng-show directive like:

```
     <div class="container marketing show-hide" ng-show="tab === 2">
```

to create dynamic pages. I want to achieve this:

Someone tries to click the "About Us" button to open it in a new tab. Instead of taking him to the frontpage in the new tab, it changes the ng-init value to 2, 3, or whatever is the value of the button clicked, so that upon opening it in a new tab, it defaults to the content assigned to the number, and not the first page, which is defined by ng-init="tab = 1"

OR

Instead of opening it a new tab, it somehow hijacks the request and just changes the ng value to the corresponding value, opening the element without opening a new tab.

Here is the website, if you are interested:

[www.kreo-it.pl](https://www.kreo-it.pl)

The point of interest are the buttons in the top navbar. Bear in mind, it's a work in progress.

Comment: I see about us displaying its own content. so what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to take advantage of [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams), something like `/:tabId` and then in your logic for that view you would show whatever is related to that `tabId`.

So for example in your controller you can bring in `$routeParams` and assign a value to `$scope.tab = $routeParams.tabId` and then your `ng-show` would pick up that value from the url that the user is currently at.

However, this does seem like a good use case for implementing a router with a `/about` route and so on for the various information that you are trying to display. Or are you not using a router currently?